# Python panda overwrite value based on conditional in other column

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

Working with the dataframe df in python pandas:

```
Product_ID  | Category  | Sub_Cat
32432           0         Gadget
24085         Big Tech    Computer
54398         Small Tech  Gadget
97456           0         Computer
```

I am working on a new column, where I will over-write the Sub_Cat value with the Category value, if it is not 0.

This is the output I am looking for:

```
Product_ID  | Category  | Sub_Cat         | Cat_for_Analysis
32432           0         Gadget            Gadget
24085         Big Tech    Computer          Big Tech
54398         Small Tech  Gadget            Small Tech
97456           0         Computer          Computer
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `ffill` after `replace` '0' to `np.nan`

```
df['Cat_for_Analysis']=df.replace('0',np.nan)[['Category','Sub_Cat']].bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
df
Out[876]: 
   Product_ID   Category   Sub_Cat Cat_for_Analysis
0       32432          0    Gadget           Gadget
1       24085    BigTech  Computer          BigTech
2       54398  SmallTech    Gadget        SmallTech
3       97456          0  Computer         Computer
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Will accept the answer the moment Stackoverflow let's me

Comment: @jeangelj yw:-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Cat_for_Analysis'] = np.where(df['Category'] == '0', df['Sub_Cat'], df['Category'])
```

Or equivalently the negated version, if it makes more intuitive sense based on your problem:

```
df['Cat_for_Analysis'] = np.where(df['Category'] != '0', df['Category'], df['Sub_Cat'])
```

The resulting output for either method:

```
   Product_ID    Category   Sub_Cat Cat_for_Analysis
0       32432           0    Gadget           Gadget
1       24085    Big Tech  Computer         Big Tech
2       54398  Small Tech    Gadget       Small Tech
3       97456           0  Computer         Computer
```

Comment: Thank You, I have been having a hard time with np.where; I was told to use loc instead?

Comment: Not sure why you'd be told to use `loc` here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use apply for this too.

```
df["Cat_for_Analysis"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["Category"] if row["Category"] != 0 else row["Sub_Cat"], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank You, what's the benefit of apply vs. the other approaches?

Comment: I would not use `apply` in this case: it's not nearly as performant as `np.where` for larger amounts of data.

Comment: @jeangelj I like it because its syntactically I find it makes more sense

Comment: @root it isn't though. If OP was working on that large of a scale then I'd probably just use pandas SQL functionality to maximize performance

Comment: `apply` is absolutely slower than `np.where`, even for intermediate size data, by orders of magnitude.